# How do I get rid of the default spacing at the top of the page, as I want to move all of my text up?

Tags: spacing, default

[image: Help!]

I want to move all of my text up, but I can't seem to control the spacing before my title. How do I proceed?

My Source code:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \Large
        \textbf{Exercice no.1}
    \end{center}

.................................................................................................................................................................................

    \\
    \\
    \Large{a)}
    \\
    \\
    \Large{$\lambda = 0$}\\ 
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow y''= 0$}\\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow {y=ax+b \quad (a,b\in\mathbb{R}) \quad} \quad 
    \textrm{OU} \quad {y=0}$}\\
    \\
    \Large{Or, une fonction du premier degré est injective et, donc, ne respecte 
    pas les conditions initiales.}\\
    \\
    \Large{d'où $y=0$ est la seule solution possible.}\\
    \\

.............................................................................................................................

    \\
    \\
    \Large{b)}
    \\
    \\
    \Large{$\lambda<0$}
    \\
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow y''-\lambda y = 0$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow y = e^{rx} \quad \textrm{[ou y=0]}$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow r^2 e^{rx} - \lambda e^{rx} = 0$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow e^{rx}(r^2-\lambda)=0$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow r^2-\lambda=0, \quad \textrm{car} \quad e^{rx}>0$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow r=\pm\sqrt\lambda \quad \in \quad \mathbb{C/R}, \quad 
    \textrm{car} \quad \lambda<0$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow r=0 \pm i\sqrt{|{\lambda}|}$}
    \\
    \Large{$\Rightarrow y=k_1cos(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x)+ik_2sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x), 
    \quad \textrm{car} \quad e^{0x}=1$}
    \\
    \\
    \Large{Or, $y(0)=k_1\neq0, \quad car \quad k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{R}/0,$}
    \\
    \Large{\qquad ce qui ne respecte donc pas les conditions initiales.}
    \\
    \\
    \Large{d'où $y=0$ est la seule solution possible.}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add code copyable to your question (no image!), then we can copy it and test it on our own computers ...

Comment: The thing is I haven't tried to get rid of it, because I have no idea how. So my code is just what you're seeing: there isn't something that like I've tried and it didn't work. But I'll put it anyway.

Comment: In principle, you could add `\vspace*{-1cm}` before `\begin{center}`, but I do not recommend doing this. Rather, I'd kindly like to ask you to look at a very basic intro to LaTeX, from which you will learn how to use templates, `enumerate` environments, `\dotfill` commands and a larger font than `10pt` instead of putting `\Large` everywhere.

Comment: … and *not* to use `\\ ` the way you are using it!

Comment: If you add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to your preamble, 1) you'll get more sensible margins 2) you'll see the title is placed right under the top margin. Moreover, it's very easy to change the margins with `geometry`.

Comment: Note that `\Large` doesn't take an argument. You could delete all the occurrences after the first one not in the `center` environment. And what marmot, GuM and Bernard said, especially what @marmot said.

Comment: Don't you get compilation errors with that code? I do.

Answer (score 1):

As posted, your code will not compile without errors. As pointed out in comments, it also suggests that you are trying to start using LaTeX without learning even the beginning basics of how it works. Please read one of the many brief introductions available as it will save you a lot of wasted time and effort, and many, many headaches, the largest and most gruesome of which will, by Sod's well-known Law, emerge mysteriously at the worst possible moment.

Here's a slightly improved version. I'm guessing that you are trying to emulate double-spacing of some kind. This isn't great in LaTeX, but `setspace` is at least minimally adequate. I've used `enumitem` so you can configure the list easily, improbably assumed that you are called 'Bob', introduced `titling`, a larger font size and, as suggested by Bernard, `geometry`. Delete the `showframe` option to remove the lines framing the page. These are just to show you the layout.

This is almost certainly not the best way to present the mathematics, but it is at least a considerable improvement, compiles (which is always a plus) and shouldn't complain too loudly about bad stuff.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling,setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\Large\bfseries}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\predate{}
\postdate{}
\setlength\droptitle{-30pt}
\title{Exercice no.1}
\author{Bob}
\date{}
\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), itemsep=20pt]
  \item $\lambda = 0$

  $\Rightarrow y''= 0$

  $\Rightarrow {y=ax+b \quad (a,b\in\mathbb{R}) \quad} \quad \textrm{OU} \quad {y=0}$

  Or, une fonction du premier degré est injective et, donc, ne respecte pas les conditions initiales.

  d'où $y=0$ est la seule solution possible.

  \item $\lambda<0$

  $\Rightarrow y''-\lambda y = 0$

  $\Rightarrow y = e^{rx} \quad \textrm{[ou y=0]}$

  $\Rightarrow r^2 e^{rx} - \lambda e^{rx} = 0$

  $\Rightarrow e^{rx}(r^2-\lambda)=0$

  $\Rightarrow r^2-\lambda=0, \quad \textrm{car} \quad e^{rx}>0$

  $\Rightarrow r=\pm\sqrt\lambda \quad \in \quad \mathbb{C/R}, \quad \textrm{car} \quad \lambda<0$

  $\Rightarrow r=0 \pm i\sqrt{|{\lambda}|}$

  $\Rightarrow y=k_1cos(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x)+ik_2sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|}x), \quad \textrm{car} \quad e^{0x}=1$

  Or, $y(0)=k_1\neq0, \quad car \quad k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{R}/0,$

  \qquad ce qui ne respecte donc pas les conditions initiales.

  d'où $y=0$ est la seule solution possible.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output with frame shown around page to indicate page layout]

Comment: oops -- working too long without my glasses.  i was thrown off by the double spacing.  erroneous comment deleted.